# Изменение громкости системного звука

Tags: java

Как изменить громкость в системе с помощью Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, это не входит библиотеки Java (всё-таки Java может бежать и на тостере, и на кофеварке, где понятие «системной громкости» лишено смысла), так что без JNI не обойтись.